Pagination in .net core mvc 6.0 is not working
I am trying to add pagination to my .net core mvc 6.0 project for that I have created a pagination class here is the code
public class PaginatedList<T>: List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize) 
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count/(double)pageSize);
        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;
    public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

    public static PaginatedList<T> Create (List<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = source.Count;
        var items = source.Skip((pageIndex-1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}

and showing pagination in the show.cshtml here is the code
 @model PaginatedList<PropertyListWithImageViewModel> // Specify the model type

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link rel=" stylesheet" href="~/Home/css/show.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
    .property-cell.spacer {
        width: 40px; /* adjust this value to set the desired spacing */
    }
</style>

<!-- start subheader -->
<section class="subHeader page">
    <div class="container">
        <h1></h1>
        <form class="searchForm" method="post" action="#">
            <input type="hidden" name="search" value="Search our site" />
        </form>
    </div><!-- end subheader container -->
</section><!-- end subheader section -->
<section id="price-drop" class="block">
    <div class="container">
        <header class="section-title">
            <h2>Properties for You</h2>
        </header>

        @if (Model.Count == 0)
        {
            <p>No properties found.</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <table class="property-table mx-auto">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i += 3)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @for (var j = i; j < Math.Min(i + 3, Model.Count); j++)
                        {
                            var propertyListing = Model[j];
                            <td class="property-cell">
                                <div class="property">
                                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@propertyListing.Id">
                                        <div class="property-image">
                                            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyListing.ImgPath))
                                            {
                                                <img src="@propertyListing.ImgPath" alt="Property Image" style="height: 330px; width: 330px;" />
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="overlay">
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <div class="tag price">&#8377; @propertyListing.AskingRate</div>
                                                <h3>@propertyListing.Address1</h3>
                                                <figure>@propertyListing.Address1</figure>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul class="additional-info">
                                                <li>
                                                    <header>Area:</header>
                                                    <figure>@propertyListing.CovArea<sup>2</sup></figure>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <header>Beds:</header>
                                                    <figure>@propertyListing.BedroomNum</figure>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <header>Baths:</header>
                                                    <figure>@propertyListing.BathroomNum</figure>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div><!-- /.property -->
                            </td>
                            @if (j < Model.Count - 1)
                            {
                                <td class="property-cell spacer"></td>
                            }
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>

        }
        @{
            var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
            var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
        }

        <a asp-action="Show" asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex -1)" class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">Prev</a>
        <a asp-action="Show" asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex +1)" class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">Next</a>
    </div>


  

</section>
<aside id="advertising" class="block">
    <div class="container">
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Enquiry">
            <div class="banner">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <span class="title">Do you want your property to be listed here?</span>
                    <span class="submit">Submit it now! <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.banner-->
        </a>
    </div>
</aside><!-- /#adveritsing-->

and in the HomeController  here my show
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Show(int? city, int? serviceReqd, int? category, int? bedroom, decimal? minPrice, decimal? maxPrice, int ? pageNumber)
    {
       IQueryable<PropertyListWithImageViewModel> query;
                else
                {
                    // All fields are filled
                    //query = query.Where(x => x.CityId == city && x.CategoryId == category && x.BedroomNum == bedroom && x.ServiceId == serviceReqd);
                    query = from p in _context.PropertyListings
                            join s in _context.ServiceReqds on p.ServiceId equals s.ServiceId
                            join pc in _context.PropertyCategories on p.CategoryId equals pc.CategoryId
                            let firstPhoto = _context.ListingPhotos.Where(lp => lp.PropertyId == p.Id).OrderBy(lp => lp.PhotoId).FirstOrDefault()
                            where p.CategoryId == category && p.ServiceId == serviceReqd && p.CityId == city && p.BedroomNum == bedroom
                            select new PropertyListWithImageViewModel
                            {
                                Id = p.Id,
                                Address1 = p.Address1,
                                Address2 = p.Address2,
                                AskingRate = p.AskingRate,
                                CovArea = p.CovArea,
                                BedroomNum = p.BedroomNum,
                                BathroomNum = p.BathroomNum,
                                ServiceName = s.ServiceName,
                                PropertyCategoryName = pc.PropertyCategoryName,
                                ImgPath = firstPhoto != null ? firstPhoto.Imgpath : string.Empty // Select the first image for each property
                            };


                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Materialize the query and project the results to PropertyListingViewModel
    var results = query.ToList();
    int pageSize = 5;
    // Pass the results to the view
    //return View(results);
    return View(PaginatedList<PropertyListWithImageViewModel>.Create(results.ToList(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
}

my problem is when i click next to see the 6th record (default is 5) the next page is showing nothing  (url-- https://localhost:7012/Home/Show?pageNumber=2) mean url is correct but no record is shown. I tried it using chatGPT and many other tools but it is showing. please help

I tried it using chatGPT, popAI and perplexity.ai google it but unable to rectify or trace the prblem i want help in that


As a first step, use Skip and Take on the query itself, don't get the full list only to ignore other pages. Second, debug your code: what do you really get from the database, and what is left after creating that PaginatedList?

this is irrelevant to your question but please have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-8.0 - your code is currently suspectible to XSS attacks.

your pagination links only send pageNumber to your controller and you are allowing nulls for everything...  (maybe add asp-route-city, asp-route-serviceReqd, etc...)

For a start your paginated list class is somewhat pointless if you have to execute and materialize the entire set of rows. I would also make the constructor private to avoid abuse and force the use of the Create() factory method. A simple fix for this would be:
private PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize) 
{
    PageIndex = pageIndex;
    TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count/(double)pageSize);
    this.AddRange(items);
}

public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;
public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

public static PaginatedList<T> Create (IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = source.Count();
    var items = source.Skip((pageIndex-1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}

Here we give it an IQueryable that it can inspect to get a count, then fetch the actual single page of results. This means EF can build a query to return 5 records instead of executing a query to return all records, just to pluck out 5.
Then when calling, do not do this:
// var results = query.ToList();

Just call it with your query:
return View(PaginatedList<PropertyListWithImageViewModel>.Create(query, pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));

As for why you don't seem to get any results for a second page, use a break-point and step through your code. Is the pageIndex coming in correctly? What is being parsed out when the PaginatedList class constructor gets called? Your code example looks to be chopped based on the orphaned else statement so it's impossible to piece together what might be happening. Step through, it could be something as silly as code re-assigning the pageIndex instead of comparing it, or conditionally your pageSize not being set and calling Create with a value of 0.

I made changes as suggested by you but I am getting this error --  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0161 'HomeController.Show(int?, int?, int?, int?, decimal?, decimal?, int?)': not all code paths return a value reCRM D:\reCRM\reCRM\reCRM\Controllers\HomeController.cs 34 Active
Please suggest as I am new to .core mvc

That means you are missing a return, I clarified the answer in that the call to PaginatedList.Create passes the IQueryable<PropertyListWithImageViewModel> not the materialized list.
